# How to run crictl command as non root user

Tags: docker, containerd, cri-o

How to run crictl as non-root user.

My docker commands work with non-root user because my user is added to docker group.

```
id
uid=1002(kube) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),10(wheel),1001(dockerroot),1002(docker)
```

I am running dockerD daemon which uses containerd and runc as runtime.

I installed crictl binary and pointed it to connect to existing dockershim socket with config file as below.

```
cat /etc/crictl.yaml
runtime-endpoint: unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock
image-endpoint: unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock
timeout: 2
debug: false
pull-image-on-create: false
```

crictl works fine with sudo but without sudo it fails like this.

```
[user@hostname~]$ crictl ps
FATA[0002] connect: connect endpoint 'unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock', make sure you are running as root and the endpoint has been started: context deadline exceeded
```

I also tried to change group of dockershim.sock to 'docker' from 'root' just like docker.sock was to try, still same.

```
srwxr-xr-x 1 root docker 0 Jan  2 23:36 /var/run/dockershim.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Jan  2 23:33 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. Create containerd group with `groupadd containerd`
2. Change containerd.socket group, located at /var/run/containerd/containerd.socket as `chgrp containerd containerd.socket`
3. Add your user to created group `usermod -aG containerd $USER`

Answer (score 0):

`sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`

or you can see [docker postinstall](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user)